# display only selected number of items in the list view in android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to display only selected items in list view.

```
public class Mact extends ListActivity {

TextView selection;
String[] items = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "record", "list",
        "contains", "some", "data","sample" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainser);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items));

    selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String text = " position:" + position + "  " + items[position];
    selection.setText(text);
}
```

}

this is my activity class which display a list view. `items` contains set of records in list view . `items` contains 10 records . I want to get list view only for starting 5 records. how can I implement it . help me out. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you create array with those 5 items? :))

Comment: its not specific like 5 .I want few records to display from starting in 1000 record for example.I want to display few

Comment: Use of baseadapter class required.

Comment: Don't assume anything while asking a question.....nobody is here free for understanding your assumption...

Comment: ok . I am having 1000 records tell me how to display starting 5 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can restrict listview items from adapter that are using for listview

Only put 5 items in the adapter. Or set getCount() return value 5.

Comment: Where he can override `getCount()`?

Comment: but he didn't created any custom adapter class yet.

Comment: better to create one custom adapter and then add this code in adapter calss

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want only 5 to show? Or do you want the list to show in a smaller space? It's possible to show all ten in a small ListView simply by setting the height value in your layout.

And if you really only want five, could you not simply create a subset of your larger strings
and pass that into the adapter?

Comment: its not specific like 5 .I want few records to display from starting in 1000 record for example.I want to display few.